# Ionic 3 App Error: Apple Mach-O Linker Error - No Push Notification Plugin, Not using CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, linker, cocoapods

I am getting an error running my Ionic app on ios via Xcode due to the error "Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error.  Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)".  I have tried every solution indicated on the other forum posts, with no luck.

1) I have tried opening .xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproj
2) I am not using push notifications plugin.  The only plugin I have added is the camera. 
3) I have tried looking in Build Phases to remove the "pods" reference, but there is no reference to pods. 
4) I have tried rebooting
5) I have tried installing cocoapods.org, removing platforms/plugins, reading plugin, rebuilding, opening .xcworkspace.

This is not a complicated app, basically created a new blank app, added camera plugin, called `getPicture` on button click, and display the picture in an `img` component.  That's it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this has already consumed hours and hours.

Comment: I found that this was something with my environment, as it compiled perfectly when I took it to a different Mac.  So I went the extreme method and reloaded my OS.  Now works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this was something with my environment, as it compiled perfectly when I took it to a different Mac. So I went the extreme method and reloaded my OS. Now works like a charm.